# vs Intellicode not working for python [ vs code extension]

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellicode

I am trying to get vs intellicode  up and running for python and there were no errors in installation.
However, I am not seeing any starred suggestions.
I did some research and found that ReSharper may cause the problem but I dont have resharper installed.

but when i checked the output of the python language server output, it read the following:

```
Current invocation parsing returned null, aborting IntelliCode recommendation!
```

I guess thats the problem.

Any solutions to get it up and running?
Thanks, in advance.

Comment: I assume you have `"python.jediEnabled": false` set? Only thing I can think of.

Comment: is it supposed to be true for it to work?

Comment: By the way, it is disabled...
Enabling it does not work either

Comment: The setting needs to be false for IntelliCode to be possible with Python.

Comment: its False,
i have also tried the troubleshooting options on their website.
sadly None Work

Comment: At this point you will have to file a bug with the IntelliCode extension and/or https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem with python in WSL. Try to disable the deeplearning model from the extension's settings.

See https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/intellicode/issues/191#issuecomment-647699535